# How to assign to a Django PointField model attribute?

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Hi I have a Django Model as follows:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    geoCoords = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True,)
```

Now I create an instance of this model:

```
A = Address()
```

How can I set the coordinates of A's geoCoord field to (5.3, 6.2)? I can't find any example of where a point field is assigned to in this way. It's such a stupidly simple question. Actually, the coordinates I would like to assign to A.geoCord are from pygeocoder. It is a 2-item tuple of floats.

The documentation on Django PointFields is basically [**non-existant**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield).

Comment: Dude, have you ever found the answer?

Comment: yeah, i would be interested in hearing that too! :P

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703975/django-sort-by-distance for practical examples.

Answer (score 28):

In newer versions of Django you can:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
pnt = Point(1, 1)
```

Plenty of examples available in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
A.geoCoords = GEOSGeometry('POINT(LON LAT)', srid=4326) #
```

where `lat` and `lon` mean `latitude` and `longitude`, respectively and `srid` is optional, indicating the `Spatial Reference System Identifier`.

You can see more on how to draw different geometries here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#what-is-geos

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

`from django.contrib.gis.db import models`

instead of
`from django.db import models`